# How can I let rsync display both total and partial progress?

Tags: linux, rsync

I've found that `rsync`'s total progress is (somewhat) shown with `--info=progress2`, while partial progress (i.e. the current file) is shown with `--info=progress` (or `-P`).

Is there a way to show both?

I've tried things like: 
`rsync -avP --info=progress --info=progress2 --progress src dst`, but that only shows total progress.

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04.2, with rsync  version 3.1.0  protocol version 31

Comment: I'd also like to know, did you find anything out?